# how can i map a key to a value or vice/versa in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a mapping as shown below, and i want to pass 1 to a function and get key a back or also pass key "a" and then get value 1 back.
what is a best way to do this via plain javascript?

```
const somemap = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3};
```

Comment: there's a way but in terms of compromise.. since that won't be a key, the most you can expect is returning the first property found having such value

Comment: Are values going to be unique?  i.e.  Should it be impossible to do something like this: `const somemap = {"a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 3};`

Comment: @Tibrogargan - yes values will be always unique.

Comment: Please update the question - this is a new requirement and very definitely will change the answer.  You should also clarify if you need one function that returns a result given either a key or a value, or if two functions are ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fulfill the conditions stated as:

*"and i want to pass 1 to a function and get key a back or also pass key "a" and then get value 1 back"*

I defined the function as `$(obj, {needle, findAsKey = false, findAsValue = false})`

***where:***

- `obj` - is the object target of the search
- `{needle}` - the search term supposedly a string when searched as key
  and anything else when searched as value.
- `{findAsKey}` - a boolean flag stating if we are willing to search
  for the `needle` as a key in the `obj` object. The default value is `false`
- `{findAsValue}` - a boolean flag stating if we are willing to search
  for the `needle` as a value in the `obj` object. The default value is `false`.

***The function returns an object containing the following properties:***

- `needle`: the term used for the search in the target object.
- `asKey`: when `needle` is used ***as key*** in the given array.

This property is set if the passed `findAsKey` was `true` and if the key was present in the target object. If the key was found, `asKey` can have any value including `null`, `undefined`, `Array`, `Object`...

- `asValue`: when `needle` is used ***as value*** in the given array (first prop found if any).

This property is set if the passed `findAsValue` flag was `true` and if the value was present in the target object. When the `needle` was found as a property value, `asValue` is expected to return a legit property name so its value can only be a valid identifier (not `undefined` or `null` but a `string` holding the js constraints).

```js
const somemap = {"a": 1, "b": [1,2,3], "c": 3};

console.log( $(somemap, {needle: 'a', findAsKey: true}) );
console.log( $(somemap, {needle: 'a', findAsValue: true}) );

console.log( $(somemap, {needle: 1, findAsKey: true}) );
console.log( $(somemap, {needle: 1, findAsValue: true}) );

console.log( $(somemap, {needle: 'c', findAsKey: true, findAsValue: true}) );
console.log( $(somemap, {needle: 'c', findAsKey: true, findAsValue: true}) );

console.log( $(somemap, {needle: "", findAsKey: true, findAsValue: true}) );
console.log( $(somemap, {needle: null, findAsKey: true, findAsValue: true}) );
console.log( $(somemap, {needle: undefined, findAsKey: true, findAsValue: true}) );

function $(obj, {needle, findAsKey = false, findAsValue = false}){
   
  const result = {needle, findAsKey, findAsValue};
  
  //set .asKey only if it was meant to be found as key
  //and the property exists in obj
  if(findAsKey && needle in obj)
    result.asKey = obj[needle];
  
  //if it was meant to be found as value
  if(findAsValue){
    //fetch the first propertyName found having that value
    const asValue = ((needle)=>{
      for([key, value] of Object.entries(obj))
        if(value === needle)
          return {result: key};
    })(needle);
    //set .asValue only if asValue was actually found
    if(asValue !== undefined)
      result.asValue = asValue.result; //no pun intended
  }
    
  return result;
}
```

Comment: `entries` is already an array, no need to unroll it

Comment: @gog yes you are right. I corrected. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't account for "or also pass key "a" and then get value 1"

Comment: @Tibrogargan I now added all the usage cases.. anyway it's a closed question with low value and probably there are tons of similar q/a

Comment: The OP definitely wants to be able to query by key too, so no - you didn't.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I totally ignored it and was surprised when I got it after you pointed out. I did a first correction in that direction for the sake of consistency

Answer (score 0):

More time consuming, less memory consuming

```js
const somemap = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3};

console.log(getValue('b'))
console.log(getKey(2))

function getValue(key) {
  return somemap[key]
}

function getKey(value) {
  return Object.entries(somemap).find(([key, val]) => val === value)[0]
}
```

Less time consuming, more memory consuming

```js
const somemap = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3};
const mapsome = invert(somemap)

console.log(getValue('b'))
console.log(getKey(2))

function getValue(key) {
  return somemap[key]
}

function getKey(value) {
  return mapsome[value]
}

function invert(obj) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => [value, key]))
}
```

Comment: Doesn't meet requirements: It's implied that it's a single function, not two.

Comment: @Tibrogargan you can be right, but the question doesn't make it clear that it has to be one function

Comment: I'd tend to agree.  It sounds like they want a single function - but definitely a place where requirements should have been clarified before delivering a product, no?  (OP just went and changed requirements too)